# GridPane position with Drag and drop

Tags: java, javafx

I want to do a drag&drop in a GridPane, and the element picked will be dropped in the cell where we drop it. But I can't find a way to get the column and the row of the cell it is supposed to be dropped to.

Here is what it looks like inside the setOnDragDropped :

```
ImageView ivPicked = new ImageView(e.getDragboard().getImage());//We get the ImageView from the Dragboard
int col = /*Put code to get the column here*/;
int row = /*Put code to get the row here*/;
grid.add(ivPicked,col,row);//Add it to the GridPane
e.consume();
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks :D

Comment: You need to fill the grid pane with some content in each grid cell (use a `Pane` of some kind: maybe a `StackPane`), and then register the drag over and drop handlers with the content of each cell.

Comment: Everything is already created, I actually want to drop it in a specific position, but I don't know how to do it.
Do I need to create a node for each cell?

Comment: Yes, create a node for each cell. If you use something like a `StackPane`, then you can just add the image view to the stack pane on which the drop occurs.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try this, I'll let you know the outcome! Thank you!